# Why are all the error cosets $Q.S$ given the erasure chain $\mathcal E$ and a syndrome $\sigma$ equiprobable? (Delfosse-Zémor)

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, toric-code

In [arXiv 1703.01517](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01517) (published [here](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.033042)), a maximum likelihood decoding for qubit loss is explained.

A quantum erasure channel erases each qubit independently with some probability $p$ and replaces it with a totally mixed state $\mathcal I/2 = \frac{1}{4}(\rho + X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z)$. This new qubit can be interpreted as the original state which suffers from a Pauli error $I, X, Y, Z$ chosen uniformly at random. The set of lost qubits is denoted $\mathcal E$ and the encoded state is subjected to a random uniform Pauli error $P$ whose support is included in $E$. This condition is denoted as $P \subset \mathcal E$.

Like for surface codes, one can measure the stabilizer generators $X_v$ and $Z_f$ and try to recover the error $P$ from its syndrome. The main difference with the Pauli channels is the additional knowledge of the erasure pattern $\mathcal E$.

Since the operators in $S$ act trivially on the code space, the goal of the decoder is to identify the coset $P.S$ of the error, knowing the set $\mathcal E$ and the syndrome $\sigma$ of $P$. The optimal strategy called *maximum likelihood decoding*, whose goal is to maximize the probability $\mathbb P(P.S|\mathcal E, \sigma)$.

Then the paper has the following statement:

*Due to the fact that errors $Q \subset \mathcal E$ are uniformly distributed,
(1) $\mathbb P(Q.S|\mathcal E, \sigma)$ is proportional to the number $|Q.S \cap \mathcal E|$ of Pauli errors of that coset that are included in $\mathcal E$. (2) This number depends only on the number $|S \cap \mathcal E|$ of stabilizers having support inside $\mathcal E$, which shows that all the cosets are equiprobable.*

I don't understand how (1) and (2) follow from the fact that individual qubit errors in $Q$ have probability $p$ and are uniformly randomly chosen from Pauli $I$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$. Can someone explain this to me?

Thinking visually, say there is a straight line erasure chain $\mathcal E$ spanning $5$ qubits in a $10 \times 10$ square lattice toric code. Then in scenario (a) suppose there is a Pauli error on only one qubit in $\mathcal E$ and in scenario (b) suppose there is a Pauli error on three different qubits in $\mathcal E$. I do not see why the cosets to which these two kinds of errors belong must have the same number of elements?